# Downloadable file from out of root directory

Tags: html, drupal

I want to create a folder named 'download' which is outside of my site root directory in drupal. Then I need to place a pdf file in that download folder. How can I give a downloadable link to this file. Any idea?

Comment: `<a href="/path/to/file.pdf">Download</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For apache, you can set up a directory alias, ie:

```
Alias /download /var/www/download
<Directory /var/www/download>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Or you can simply use a symbolic link for this task:

```
ln -s /var/www/download /var/www/myproject/download
```

Be sure to enable symbolic links for your web server.

Comment: the above one is the target pdf user has to download...i really struck.......and this is on live...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $file = '/full/path/below/root/secret.pdf';

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
?>
```

Comment: John thanks for reply, $file = '/full/path/below/root/secret.pdf'; Just confusing. My root directory as www/myproject. i need to add download folder as in www/download/file.pdf . Now u can see www/myproject and www/download. So how can i give path.